# Trying to call/post a third party api in java spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, http

My issue is when I try this I get a media type error, then I changed the header. Now I receive a 500 error. The problem isnt the api , on postman it works perfectly , am I doing something wrong in my code when requesting a post?

My object model

```java
public class EmailModel {
    
    private String module;
    private String notificationGroupType;
    private String notificationGroupCode;
    private String notificationType;
    private String inLineRecipients;
    private String eventCode;
    private HashMap<String, Object> metaData;

    public EmailModel() {
        this.module = "CORE";
        this.notificationGroupType = "PORTAL";
        this.notificationGroupCode = "DEFAULT";
        this.notificationType = "EMAIL";
        this.inLineRecipients = "[chrispotjnr@gmail.com,chris@mqattach.com]";
        this.eventCode = "DEFAULT";
        this.metaData = metaData;
    }
}
```

My Controller
It should send a post request with a object body, the emails get sent

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "test", method = RequestMethod.Post)
public void post() throws Exception {
    String uri = "TestUrl";

    EmailModel em = new EmailModel();
    EmailModel data = em;

    HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder().build();
    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
        .headers("Content-Type", "application/json")
        .uri(URI.create(uri))
        .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(String.valueOf(data)))
        .build();

    HttpResponse<?> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.discarding());
    System.out.println(em);
    System.out.println(response.statusCode());
}
```

[postmanImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAcQG.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must to convert `EmailModel` to `json` format by `ObjectMapper`

```java
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
String data = objectMapper
      .writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
      .writeValueAsString(em);
```

and change `POST` to :

```java
.POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(data))
```

See more about [ObjectMapper](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial#1-java-object-to-json)

Answer (score 0):

Capture requests and cookies(on the left side of setting icon)
->Request
->port and put the port number there

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).